# Tensorboard libprotobuf.so.23: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, ubuntu, tensorboard

Hello I want to use tensorboard but I cant start it.
I am using anaconda on ubunutu and installed it with `pip install tensorboard`.
I get this error when I try to start tensorboard with `tensorboard --logdir .` :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myhome/anaconda3/bin/tensorboard", line 5, in <module>
    from tensorboard.main import run_main
  File "/home/myhome/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/main.py", line 43, in <module>
    from tensorboard import default
  File "/home/myhome/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/default.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.audio import audio_plugin
  File "/home/myhome/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/plugins/audio/audio_plugin.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.audio import metadata
  File "/home/myhome/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/plugins/audio/metadata.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorboard.compat.proto import summary_pb2
  File "/home/myhome/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/proto/summary_pb2.py", line 8, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "/home/myhome/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 48, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: libprotobuf.so.23: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried out tensorboard version 2.2.0 and the latest version. But on both I get the same error.

conda-version: 4.9.1

Comment: Ubuntu : libprotobuf17 → Provides libprotobuf.so.17 ..... and libprotobuf-c1 → Provides libprotobuf-c.so.1 ........ For libprotobuf.so.23 : Build protobuf e.g. version 3.12.4 to get `libprotobuf.so.23 -> libprotobuf.so.23.0.4`

Comment: Source code `protobuf-3.12.4-all.tar.gz` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z5Ev6AWMJet1p_gic9hTf55gsqjPUsdE/view?usp=sharing